# Silent in-place upgrade, Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working on a process to upgrade over a hundred Server 2008 R2 boxes to Server 2012 R2.  My client wants to do an in place upgrade so they don't have to reconfigure roles and features etc.  This means I will unpack the Server 2012 R2 ISO and execute "setup.exe /unattend:unattend.xml".

I am using WSIM to generate the unattend but I am getting stuck on how to select the OS version (Windows Server 2012 SERVERSTANDARD in this case).  Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARD</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UpgradeData>
                <Upgrade>true</Upgrade>
            </UpgradeData>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

This is the section which I believe should auto-select the OS version:

```
  <ImageInstall>
                    <OSImage>
                        <InstallFrom>
                            <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                                <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                                <Value>Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARD</Value>
                            </MetaData>
                        </InstallFrom>
                    </OSImage>
                </ImageInstall>
```

Unfortunately when I run setup.exe /unattend:unattend.xml I get this error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTkqD.png)

"Windows could not process the  settings in the unattend answer file."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I am wondering if the WinPE pass is the culprit, since I am not using a pre-boot environment.  I am executing setup.exe from the live Server 2008 R2 OS.

TIA

Comment: Do you need to specify a path? The sample I see at [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-imageinstall-dataimage-installfrom) includes `<Path>\\networkshare\share\install.wim</Path>`.

Comment: Additionally, don't you need to specify `<InstallTo>`?

Answer (score 0):

you missed this :

```
<InstallTo>
    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
    <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
```

Full node/child :

```
<ImageInstall>
            <OSImage>
                <InstallFrom>
        <Path>install.wim</Path>
                    <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                        <Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
                        <Value>2</Value>
                    </MetaData>
                </InstallFrom>
            <InstallTo>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                </InstallTo>
            </OSImage>
        </ImageInstall>
```

I know that's an old post, but maybe it helps for someone!